# generating graph with random edges

Tags: c, algorithm, math, random

I am trying to write a c/c++ program that uses Disjoint Sets using union by rank and path compression Graph Algorithm then apply Kruskal's algorithm on that graph.I already generated number_of_vertices-1 pairs (0,1),(1,2)...(n-2,n-1) as edges in the graph in order to make the graph connected.  I need to generate the rest of 3*number_Of_Vertices+1 random edges as pairs of (vertex1,vertex2) without collisions(the same edge shall not be generated twice). I have to do this without using extra memory. By extra memory i mean an extra list, vector...Do you guyz have any idea how to do this?

This is what i did until now but it surely has collisions:

```
edge** createRandomEdges(nodeG **nodeArray, int n) {
    edge **edgeArray = (edge**)malloc(sizeof(edge*)*n * 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        edgeArray[i] = createEdge(nodeArray[0], nodeArray[i + 1], rand() % 100+1);
    for (int i = n; i < 4 * n; i++) {
       int nodeAindex = rand() % n;
       int nodeBindex = rand() % n;

       while (nodeAindex == nodeBindex) {
           nodeAindex = rand() % n;
           nodeBindex = rand() % n;
       }

       int weight = rand() % 100 + 1;
       edgeArray[i] = createEdge(nodeArray[nodeAindex], nodeArray[nodeBindex], weight);
   }

   return edgeArray;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a c or a c++ solution? Both languages offer different solutions. Your example looks like c, and you have both languages tagged.

Comment: I am good with any language solution, i just want the algorithm. Yes, my code is wrote in C

Comment: If you are looking to discuss algorithms, you may want to ask in a more appropriate stack exchange site. Perhaps https://cs.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Algorithms are not off-topic on SO, and programming questions are explicitly off-topic on cs.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

So you have N edges and want to mark K of them optimizing memory consumption. In this case you can use [Reservoir sampling](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) with O(K) memory complexity.

Make an array of integers with size K, fill it with 0..K-1 numbers, then walk a loop and randomly replace some numbers using rules that provide uniformity

```
ReservoirSample(S[1..n], R[1..k])
  // fill the reservoir array
  for i = 1 to k
      R[i] := S[i]

  // replace elements with gradually decreasing probability
  for i = k+1 to n
    j := random(1, i)   // important: inclusive range
    if j <= k
        R[j] := S[i]
```